# Does Trump claim that election irregularities only affected the Presidential election?

Tags: united-states, election, donald-trump, election-fraud

Donald Trump has been contesting the results of the 2020 Presidential election, alleging voter fraud, improper counting, and other irregularities. A number of recounts have been done, although none changed the results in their districts.

Many Republicans won down-ballot races, so if he were successful in challenging the processes, it seems like this could invalidate those results as well. This seems like it would be undesirable for the GOP, but it hasn't stopped Republican leaders from going along with his challenges.

Does he claim that this only applied to votes for President? And if so, how does he claim this was done?

And why would whoever is perpetrating the fraud limit it just to the President? If there were a Democratic conspiracy, surely they would also want to get more Democrats into Congress as well (in particular, control of the Senate wouldn't be hinging on the results of the Georgia runoffs). Would it have been too conspicuous if they were *too* successful?

Comment: Comments deleted.  Comments should be used to improve the question, not debate its subject matter. For more information on how comments should and should not be used, please review [the help article about the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Whether or not election fraud took place during the election is irrelevant to the question at hand, because it only asks what claims a specific politician made.